# Reading pdf from url with node.js using PDF.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf.js

I'm trying to extract the text of a pdf from the pdf's url. Following the example on the pdf.js website, i understand how to render a pdf on client-side, but I'm running into issues when I do this server-side.

I downloaded the package using  `npm i pdfjs-dist`

I tried the code below as a simple example to load the pdf:

```
var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/examples/learning/helloworld.pdf';
var pdfjsLib = require("pdfjs-dist")
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);

loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdf) {
    console.log(pdf);
}).catch(function (error){
    console.log(error)
})
```

But when I run this, I get the following error:

```
  message: 'The browser/environment lacks native support for critical functionality used by the PDF.js library (e.g. `ReadableStream` and/or `Promise.allSettled`); please use an ES5-compatible build instead.',
  name: 'UnknownErrorException',
  details: 'Error: The browser/environment lacks native support for critical functionality used by the PDF.js library (e.g. `ReadableStream` and/or `Promise.allSettled`); please use an ES5-compatible build instead.'
```

Any ideas on how to go about doing this? All I'm trying to do is extract the text of a pdf from it's URL. And I'm trying to do this server side using nodejs. Appreciate any input!

Answer (score 14):

You need to import the es5 build of pdf.js. The code below should work:

```
var pdfjsLib = require("pdfjs-dist/es5/build/pdf.js");
var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/examples/learning/helloworld.pdf';
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);

loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdf) {
    console.log(pdf);
}).catch(function (error){
    console.log(error)
})
```

Also check out https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/node/getinfo.js for a working example with node.js

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem (*The browser/environment lacks native support for critical functionality used by the ****PDF.js** library** (e.g. `ReadableStream` and/or `Promise.allSettled`); please use an **ES5-compatible build** instead.*) but with **Angular 8** so here I leave the solution in case someone needs it:

`packaje.json` configuration:

- Angular versión: `8.2.14`
- pdfjs-dist: `2.4.456`

component:

```
import * as pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist/es5/build/pdf';
import { pdfjsworker } from 'pdfjs-dist/es5/build/pdf.worker.entry';

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsworker;
```

Comment: Sweet Solution. I was facing same issue in the react (17.0) app and I was using react-pdf module but later removed that installed the said version and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I've also faced the same issue in latest version of pdfjs-dist (2.8.335) while using it in a node js project and as mentioned in other answers that we need to change path to fix this.

But in my case path - `pdfjs-dist/es5/build/pdf` didn't work.

In latest version it got changed to `pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js`